# Changing a value in config.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord

I want to change the value of conf.perms.commands in my mercyxrd.js config file as seen in the below command,
please help me on how to do this (:

```
const conf = require("../../mercyxrd.js")
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs');
class roller extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: "roles",
            aliases: ["roles"],
            usage: "roles",
            description: "bu komut hakkında bilgi bulunmuyor."
        });
    }
async run(message, args, perm) {
    if(message.author.id !== "411621794131476480") return
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(`specify an argument`))

    if(args[0] == "register-auth") {
    let rol = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args.splice(1)[0]) || message.guild.roles.cache.find(r=>r.name===args.splice(1).join(''));
    if(!rol) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(`please specify a role`)).then(x=>x.delete({timeout: 9000}))


  //In this part, I want to change the value in my config file. conf.perms.commands


    message.channel.send(`${rol} designated as the registration role.`)
        }
    
}};

module.exports = roller;
```

Comment: why not : conf.perms.commands = xxx ?

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Comment: you want to rewrite the config file ?

Comment: hmm Definitely no